# Как в браузере вывести 3D анимацию модели сделанной в 3ds max?

Tags: javascript, анимация, 3d, webgl

Необходимо в браузере выводить анимированные модели, сделанные в 3ds max (с возможностью управления камерой). Просто модель и ее какая-то анимация.

1. Возможно ли такое в принципе? Если да, то что посоветуете почитать?
2. Возможно ли такое без использования флэша/юнити?
3. Возможно ли такое на js-e (быть может, плагины какие-то, что конвертируют модель)?

Comment: three.js - копайте в этом направлении.

Comment: Google: webgl 3dmax model animation

Answer (score 1):

[three.js](http://threejs.org/), легче всего сделать через collada loader, вот [пример](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_collada).

Comment: лучше привести решение прямо в ответе, а ссылку использовать в качестве иллюстрации.